# Location of AntiSamy policy file in web project

Tags: java, struts, antisamy

I'm trying to use *AntiSamy* to prevent XSS attacks on my site. I downloaded the following jars and added them to "/WEB-INF/lib"

- antisamy-1.5.3.jar
- nekohtml.jar
- xercesImpl-2.5.0.jar

along with a policy file **antisamy-slashdot-1.4.4.xml** in "/WEB-INF".

I tried to implement a filter through **web.xml**. A snippet of the servlet I'm using is

```
public class AntiSamyFilter implements Filter {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AntiSamyFilter.class);

private final AntiSamy antiSamy;

public AntiSamyFilter() {
    try {
        URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("antisamy-slashdot-1.4.4.xml");
        LOG.info("After getResource");
        Policy policy = Policy.getInstance(url.getFile()); //Deployment fails
        LOG.info("After Policy");
        antiSamy = new AntiSamy(policy);
        LOG.info("After antiSamy");
    } catch (PolicyException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
}
```

The deployment fails after **Policy policy = Policy.getInstance(url.getFile());**. It's probably because of the path of the policy file.

Can someone please tell me where the policy file should be kept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `url.getFile` part fails because it couldn't find the `antisamy-slashdot-1.4.4.xml` file. I created a package in `src/my/package` and changed

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("antisamy-slashdot-1.4.4.xml");
```

to

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/my/package/antisamy-slashdot-1.4.4.xml");
```

I also added `batik.jar` along with the other jar files. It solved my problem